# Why is the summary and body returning an empty object using the Element API?

Tags: plugin-elementapi

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I'm getting an empty object back from the Element API for the summary and/or body for any given entry.

**elementapi.php**

```
...
'transformer' => function (EntryModel $entry) {
    return [
        'title' => $entry->title,
        'url' => $entry->url,
        'summary' => $entry->summary
    ];
},
...
```

Here is the json I am getting back:

```
{"data":[{"title":"My Title","url":"http:\/\/local.mysite.dev\/section\/my-entry","summary":{}}
```

**EDIT/SOLUTION**

Thank you again @Oliver!

I wanted to update my post in the event someone else came across it. I am using [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) to render my html from the json that is getting output via the ElementAPI.

By casting the summary as a string, you will need to tell mustache to parse the html by using three curly-brackets instead of the usual two.

**mustache**

```
<p>Title: {{title}}</p>
<p>URL: {{url}}</p>
{{{ summary }}}
```

Otherwise you will end up with something that looks like this:

```
Title: My Title
URL: www.mysite.com
<p>This is my summary</p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
'transformer' => function (EntryModel $entry) {
    return [
        'title' => $entry->title,
        'url' => $entry->url,
        'summary' => (string) $entry->summary
    ];
},
...
```

Comment: Hi Oliver - thank you, that did it! 
I don't get it though. Was/is it something I did that I have to cast the summary as a string?

Comment: Hey, I can't remember where I found this but no, you didn't do anything wrong. Rich text field just need to be cast as string to return the html as a string :)