# Rich Text Field is returning an empty object over api of plugin json_expand

Tags: plugin-jsonexpand

Is anybody using the [json_expand plugin](https://github.com/familiar-studio/craft-json-expand) for API functionality?
For the entry type Rich Text Field its just returning an empty object.

This is my json_expand endpoint:

```
{% header "Content-Type: application/json" %}
{% set utensils = craft.entries.section('utensils').find('') %}
{{ utensils | json_expand | raw  }}
```

It's returning everything except that Rich Text field which just returns this:

```
"utensil_textbox": {}
```

Comment: Total shot in the dark, but scroll to the bottom of [this thread](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12515/why-is-the-summary-and-body-returning-an-empty-object-using-the-element-api/12577) I was having a similar problem with using the ElementAPI + rich text field.

Comment: Never used JSON Expand plugin, but try this:  `{{ utensils.getRawContent() | json_expand | raw  }}`

Answer (score 3):

I just came across this problem and solved it by editing the **JsonExpandService.php** file (located in craft/plugins/jsonexpand/services/) in two places.

Change line 101 from this:

```
$relatedArray[$subHandle] = $subValue;
```

To this:

```
if($subField['type'] == "RichText") {
    // Rich Text field values need to be converted to a string
    $relatedArray[$subHandle] = (string)$subValue;
} else {
    $relatedArray[$subHandle] = $subValue;
}
```

And change line 115 from this:

```
$entryData[$handle] = $value;
```

To this:

```
if($field['type'] == "RichText") {
    $entryData[$handle] = (string)$value;
} else {
    $entryData[$handle] = $value;
}
```

This fixed Rich Text fields coming through as empty objects for me.

This plugin hasn't been updated in 3 years, so Craft probably changed something about how Rich Text fields are outputted and the plugin never adjusted. Just a guess.